# Restricting divisors to closed fiber of relative curve over henselian DVR

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

### Setup:

$k$ is an algebraically closed field.

$\mathcal{O} = k\{t\}$ is the henselization of $k[t]_{(t)}$.

$V \rightarrow \text{Spec}(\mathcal{O})$ is proper and has a section.

$V$ is irreducible, nonsingular, and of dimension $2$.

$X$ is the closed fiber of $V$.

## Question:

Why is $\text{ker}(\text{Pic}(V) \rightarrow \text{Pic}(X))$ uniquely divisible by $n$ when $n$ is prime to $\text{char}(k)$?

This is claimed (no proof) in Artin, Grothendieck Topologies, Prop. 4.4.2.

[Posted first on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3048709/restricting-divisors-to-closed-fiber-of-relative-curve-over-henselian-dvr))

Comment: This follows from proper base change and the surjectivity of $\text{Pic}(V) \rightarrow \text{Pic}(X)$.